# Getting the access token for service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

I have external project in the google console that is unverified and 100 users cap is not exhausted.

If anybody will get access for some scopes of my project via oauth consent screen, can I request access token via service account ('sub' => 'that-user@gmail.com') for that user and that scopes?

And what will happen if project is verified by google assessors?

Comment: Please clarify your question. In one part you mention a service account token and in another part creating a token for a user. Are you attempting account impersonation? Clearly explain your problem and what solution you looking for.

Comment: Step 1: My web application redirects the user to OAuth login page and OAuth consent screen where user authenticates with google and approves required scopes. Then google redirects the user back to my application with special code in request. The next my application using code do authentication request and gets access token and make sure that required scopes are approved. The next using this access token my application requests "userinfo" and gets the email of authenticated user.

Comment: Step 2: My application needs to sync google contacts using "People API" in the background (without any users actions). But my application can not use access token received from the web client in first step because it's life time is limited to 30 minutes. That's why I need to request new access token using the service account with ('sub' => 'that-user@gmail.com') to act from name of that user and by server to server requests only. And it must work for any user (outside of organization).

Comment: I have 2 projects in google console:
--- The first project is verified by google and it works fine with "Step 2" for any user, but it doesn't have verified scopes for "People API". 
--- The second project is unverified and I always have the huge error on "Step 2" that i can not fix: "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested."

Comment: Please add this information by editing your question and not with comments.

Comment: Note: If your code wants to impersonate a user account, you must have domain-wide delegation enabled in Google Workplace. You cannot impersonate other types of users. 2) Why is their token only valid for 30 minutes? Why not refresh the token?